# Client setting for FreeIPA Puppet module not working

Tags: puppet, freeipa

I'm trying to use the [FreeIPA Puppet module](https://forge.puppet.com/adullact/freeipa), and I copied the below module, changing the data to reflect my environment.

```
class {'freeipa':
    ipa_role             => 'client',
    domain               => 'example.lan',
    domain_join_password => 'vagrant123',
    install_epel         => true,
    ipa_master_fqdn      => 'ipa-server-1.example.lan',
}
```

Unfortunately, using this code gave me the following error:

```
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Class[Freeipa]:
  has no parameter named 'domain_join_password'
  expects a value for parameter 'ip_address' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:322:2 on node puppet-agent
```

I tried to see if other people had implemented this module and found nothing. I went to their GitLab repository [here](https://gitlab.adullact.net/adullact/puppet-freeipa/blob/master/REFERENCE.md), and could not find any reference of the client configuration. Perhaps it's new, or the documentation is outdated and the functionality was removed? If someone has experience with this, please point me in the right direction on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm that there is no class parameter `domain_join_password` by looking at the source in `./freeipa/manifests/init.pp`. Their documentation appears to be out of date.

Looking at the history of `init.pp`, the parameter was removed in [this commit](https://gitlab.adullact.net/adullact/puppet-freeipa/commit/985b34b864bace15e74937cf6c109e905bec1f59) 3 months ago. It seems to have been renamed to `password_usedto_joindomain`.

Comment: Your comment helped because between this and viewing the issues in the error output I was able to get it to work. For those looking for the rest of the solution, add the `password_usedto_joindomain`, `puppet_admin_password`, `directory_services_password`, and `ip_address` attributes to the class to install the client. The IP address must be the IP address of the client machine so you can use the `$ipaddress` fact to set it.

Comment: Well it was working, but I realized the reason why is because I had already installed the freeipa-client on there. I uninstalled it and I'm now getting a different error, but I'll post a different question for that one and mark this one resolved, since the structure of the class is fine, it's the data that's incorrect now.